# Housekeeping on Application crash

Tags: android, mobile, garbage-collection

I there a place where I can do some housekeeping activities if an Android application crashes for some reason? Some things like closing handles, connections etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() to register for crash events. Though if your entire app crashes you don't have to worry about closing connections as they will all be killed along with the app.

Comment: What is the difference between this and setUncaughtExceptionHandler() ?

Comment: I think the exception handler used by the thread is the one set by `setUncaughtExceptionHandler()` if it exists, if not then it will use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` (if it exists).

Answer (score 0):

The OS kernel will close all your open filehandles, sockets, allocated memory, and so forth. It can't flush buffered IO internal to the program, and it'll just tear down your TCP sockets without saying `BYE` to the remote peer, but there isn't much you can (or need) to do when the OS reaps your process.

But you might need to do some cleanup at next startup, if your application crashed while leaving inconsistent data on the persistent storage.

Comment: Actually I have my own objects which are cached to be sent to a consistent state. So OS may not be of help to me.

Comment: Journaling filesystems write metadata changes to disk twice: first to the journal, then to the filesystem, then they set a flag in the journal to indicate that those changes were successfully stored. When one comes back up unclean, it scans  the journal and re-applies all changes that weren't marked successful. You could update a 'clean' or 'dirty' flag on your objects when they are consistent or inconsistent, so at next start up you can delete the inconsistent objects.